# Can't create table `prueba_test`.`evento_hora` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")

Tags: sql

Estoy queriendo resolver agrupar eventos por la fecha y que cada evento tenga una hora. Cree 2 tablas:
**eventos**
id
titulo
fecha

**horas**
id
hora

Tengo una tabla pivot
**evento_hora**
fecha_evento
id_hora

Relacionada por la columna fecha_evento con la tabla eventos y por la columna id_hora con la tabla horas. Así podría obtener eventos de una determinada fecha. Antes pregunto si es que hay otra forma de hacer lo mismo. Al querer hacerlo en Laravel 8 me sale error de construcción cuando quiero relacionarlas por la fecha que seria en mi solución tipo string

events

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->string('name',120);
        $table->string('fecha',120);
        $table->timestamps();

        //rell

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

        
    });
```

horas

```
Schema::create('horas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');

        $table->string('hora',120);

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

tabla PIVOT

```
Schema::create('evento_hora', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('fecha_evento',120);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('hora_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        //rell

        $table->foreign('fecha_evento')->references('fecha')->on('events')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');

         $table->foreign('hora_id')->references('id')->on('horas')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

ERROR:

Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.3 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.3 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.2 seconds)
Migrating: 2021_09_23_145849_create_categories_table
Migrated:  2021_09_23_145849_create_categories_table (0.2 seconds)
Migrating: 2021_09_23_145942_create_events_table
Migrated:  2021_09_23_145942_create_events_table (0.76 seconds)
Migrating: 2021_09_23_205142_create_horas_table
Migrated:  2021_09_23_205142_create_horas_table (0.19 seconds)
Migrating: 2021_09_23_205235_create_evento_hora_table

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `prueba_test`.`evento_hora` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `evento_hora` add constraint `evento_hora_fecha_evento_foreign` foreign key (`fecha_evento`) references `events` (`fecha`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

at D:\xampp\htdocs\calendario_web\nueva_prueba\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
668|         catch (Exception $e) {

> 669|             throw new QueryException(
> 670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> 671|             );
> 672|         }
> 673|

Exception trace:

1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `prueba_test`.`evento_hora` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
D:\xampp\htdocs\calendario_web\nueva_prueba\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463

2   PDOStatement::execute()
D:\xampp\htdocs\calendario_web\nueva_prueba\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:463

Please use the argument -v to see more details.

Comment: Por favor aporta un  [mcve] así como el mensaje de error de forma íntegra

Comment: Gracias por responder, actualicé el post con las migraciones y el mensaje de error del la consola

Comment: Las foreign key no se relacionan solo con el id?

Comment: Te recomiendo que en la tabla evento_hora uses como referencia el id, en vez de el string que estás usando, de la tabla horas, a la larga te servirá para crear seeders o factories, también para hacer búsquedas o insertar datos. En cuanto al error, te dice que la clave ajena es errónea, seguramente porque no estás referenciando a una clave primaria, por lo que la referencia podría ser nula.